# Fire onkeyup in generated table with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onkeyup

I've got a small problem in my javascript which i am stuck on for a while now.
What i did is :

1. Create an empty table.
2. Generate the tr/td tags and values inside the table(from JSON-object).

   ```
   for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
       var row$ = $('<tr/>');
       for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
           var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

           if(colIndex == columns.indexOf("type")) 
           {

               var box$ = $('<td/>');
               if(cellValue == "Organisation")
               box$.addClass( "uk-badge uk-badge-danger" );
               else
               box$.addClass( "uk-badge uk-badge-primary" );
               box$.html(cellValue);
               row$.append(box$);

           } 
           else 
           { 
               var box$ = $('<td/>');
               box$.html(cellValue);
               box$.attr('contenteditable','true');
               box$.attr('onkeyup','updateJSON('+colIndex+','+i+')');
               row$.append(box$);
           }


       }
       $(selector).append(row$);

   }
   ```
3. table looks fine:

td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="updateJSON(3,0)">Timmy/td>

The problem occurs when the table is generated and i edit a field. the 'onkeyup' does not 'fire' while it should. Replacing the 'onkeyup' with an 'onclick' works just fine. I have no clue why this does not work, can anybody help?

```js
var myList = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "arnold"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "hans"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "jack"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Peter"
  }];

 function loadDoc3() {
    $("#RelationDataTable tr").remove();
    buildHtmlTable('#RelationDataTable');
 }

 // Builds the HTML Table out of myList.
 function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
  var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);

  for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
   var row$ = $('<tr/>');
   for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
    var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

    if(colIndex == columns.indexOf("type")) 
    {
     
     var box$ = $('<td/>');
     if(cellValue == "Organisation")
     box$.addClass( "uk-badge uk-badge-danger" );
     else
     box$.addClass( "uk-badge uk-badge-primary" );
     box$.html(cellValue);
     row$.append(box$);
     
    } 
    else 
    { 
     var box$ = $('<td/>');
     box$.html(cellValue);
                    box$.attr('contenteditable','true');
     box$.attr('onkeyup','updateJSON('+colIndex+','+i+')');
     //box$.click(function() {
//  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
//});
     row$.append(box$);
    }

    
   }
   $(selector).append(row$);
  
  }
 }
 var currentcolumns = [];


 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

  for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
   var rowHash = myList[i];
   for (var key in rowHash) {
    if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1 && key != "id") {
     columnSet.push(key);
     headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
    }
   }
  }
  $("#RelationDataTable").append(headerTr$);
  currentcolumns = columnSet;
  return columnSet;
 }
 function updateJSON(xx,y)
 {
  var cellValue = myList[y][currentcolumns[xx]];
  alert(document.getElementById("RelationDataTable").rows[y+1].cells[xx].firstChild.nodeValue);
  myList[y][currentcolumns[xx]] = document.getElementById("RelationDataTable").rows[y+1].cells[xx].firstChild.nodeValue;
  x = 2;
 }
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<input id="searchname" type="text" name="InsertSearchname" onkeyup="loadDoc3()"><h2>Search Contact</h2>
<table id="RelationDataTable">
      <thead>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: Have you checked the JQuery [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function?

Comment: i tried the following but it does not generate html with an onkeyup tag/or fires the onkeyup event:

var box$ = $('<td/>');
box$.html(cellValue);
     //box$.attr('onkeyup','updateJSON('+colIndex+','+i+')');
box$.keyup(function() {
alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
row$.append(box$);

Comment: Can you expose a bit more of your code? Perhaps create a codepen or jsfiddle so we can see it in action.

Comment: if i change the 'keyup' to 'click' it works fine.

Comment: See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/Lmxtuhds/1/ It should work. Something else must be going on with your code.

Comment: @Arg0n hmm weird im doing something wrong but i cant figure out what. There is a working samle of what is not working. The items get an "onkeyup"-event but they do not trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contenteditable="true"` should be set for your `<td>` elements, not on the `<table>`.

Otherwise the `td` will not trigger an event.

So add `box$.attr('contenteditable','true');` in your loop.

Comment: It does not seem to work(see the snippit). I am probably doing some very small thing wrong.

Comment: Can you try removing `contenteditable="true"` from your `<table>`?